# Simple C# application not working correctly, works fine when run from within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, file-io

I'm new to C# and VS, and I have a bizarre problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ExampleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\TEST.TXT");
            fi.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("File exists: {0}", fi.Exists);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my program, it creates a file TEST.TXT. When I run the program inside VS 2010 with the Debug -> Start Debugging command (F5), the program works fine and the file is created.

However if I build the solution then run the program from the .exe using cmd prompt:

```
C:\...\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExampleApplication\ExampleApplication\bin\Debug\ExampleApplication.exe
```

It runs outputting: **File exists: true**. But the file is not created. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Its propably a rights problem. Try running your exe with admin rights, and see if that works.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't exist? The line `fi.Create()` explicitly creates the file.

Comment: The file definitely doesn't exist. When I run it from within VS it is created fine. I've run the .exe with admin rights, still no fix. I've modified the program to write more information it now prints:

Comment: File exists: True
File name: C:\TEST.TXT
File length: 0, but it isn't actually there. If I try to open it from notepad or just look in explorer its not there.

Comment: Tried on my PC (Win7x64 Net4) and works as expected! Probably a permission problem. Have you tried to manually create a file in your root dir (Notepad) ?

Comment: on which version of Windows are you trying this, if Win7 is UAC turned on?

Comment: UAC is off. Tried running as Admin, I can create files in C:/ fine. I think im going to give up for this evening. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @RickyJones: See my answer below.

Comment: @RickyJones UAC will redirect file reads and writes even when it is "off".  Have you checked the VirtualStore directory?  (See my answer below for more detail.)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps file stream eventually was not released by OS so file system does not reflect recent changes? Just try explicitly closing a new file stream after creation:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\TEST.TXT");
using (var stream = fi.Create());
```

Please let us know whether it works or not since it is a bit crazy idea ;) I believe problem could be even simple

Comment: @RickyJones: have you shared exact source code you are using? perhaps you ahve removed asoemthing small you considered not important? Please share exact code, perhaps you have something like `Console.ReadLine()` or whatever what you've skipped when posting here?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that User Account Control is redirecting the file creation to the shadow copy directory; under VS you're running as an administrator, so the file creation is not redirected.

Have a look for the file in the VirtualStore directory.  That will be at

```
C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Local\VirtualStore
```

The actual folder will be something like

```
C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\C
```

To solve this problem, you could change the program so that it writes the file to a location intended for user data; an obvious choice would be the `Documents` folder.  You could also run the application with administrator privileges.  There are at least three ways to do this:

- Right-click the executable and choose "Run as Administrator"
- Run the executable with a shortcut, after checking the "Run as Administrator" check box in the shortcut's properties dialogue
- Use either method above to open an "Administrator" command prompt session; then run the application normally by entering its name at the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a permissions problem. If the user account running vS is different from the one running the command prompt, they may have different permissions for creating files. Look in your Windows event viewer to see if the error is reported there. Then, use try-catch, as Marc suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip. When you work with files, always do it in a try catch. You never know what could happen like in your case.

Do you run the cmd as administrator? Maybe you don't have the rights to create the file.

Also add a try catch and return the error in the console. It would help you to figure out your problem if running as administrator doesn't work.

```
        try
        {            
            your code..
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but no exception is being thrown.

Comment: Do you run the cmd as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason of this, but why won't you try this:

```
if(!File.Exists("C:\\TEST.TXT"))
{
   File.Create("C:\\TEST.TXT");
   Console.WriteLine("File exists");
}
```

Comment: Fun ;) It would print `File does not exists` when file actually exists ;)

Comment: you mean it created a file but writed 'File does not exists'?

Comment: Just read your `else` block, it will run in case when `File.Exists("C:\\TEST.TXT") == true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call fi.Refresh(); in order to have the FileSystemInfo re-examine the base object, otherwise, it will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

Try to close the file as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ExampleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\TEST.TXT");
            fi.Create();
            fi.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("File exists: {0}", fi.Exists);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileInfo` does not provide `Close` method, perhaps you mean `FileStream.Close()`?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the wrong way. You have to dispose the file object after you're done with it. To create an empty file in .NET, I'd suggest you do it like this:

```
using (File.Create("C:\\TEST.TXT"));
```

or like this:

```
File.Create("C:\\TEST.TXT").Dispose();
```

Alternatively you could just modify your `fi.Create()` to:

```
fi.Create().Dispose();
```

It is likely that Visual Studio Debugger is automatically cleaning up your mess for you by properly disposing all objects when you stop the debugging.

Comment: Also, before trying this code, I'd suggest you restart your PC just to make sure windows doesn't try to use the same memory space again.

Answer (score 1):

```
use the following code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ExampleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
         if(!File.Exists("C:\\TEST.TXT"))
         {
             GC.Collect();
             GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
             fi.Create();
             fi.Close();
             Console.WriteLine("File exists: {0}", fi.Exists);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution,

I ran you code and got a UnauthorizedAccessException which is a security exception
you do not have the right security to save a file in the root folder (C:\)

if you change it to FileInfo("TEXT.TXT"); instead of C:\TEXT.TXT
it will work

Btw, you cant use a using statement as FileInfo doesn't implement IDisposable interface.